# Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution\n\tat after deploying my spring boot app on google cloud / app engine

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, spring-jdbc

After deploying my spring boot on google cloud platform app engine 'standard', and then try to visit the website I get Error: Server Error in browser. Then I visit the log on google cloud I get error:

```
"logMessage": "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter doStart: \norg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution\n\tat
```

I tried to change the datasourceurl multiple time, but still not succeeded yet.

My properties file:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

database=mysql
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/myBlog?cloudSqlInstance=reviewcontainerblog&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory

spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
#JPA
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect
```

my pom file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <groupId>com.reviewcontainer</groupId>
    <artifactId>ReviewContainer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ReviewContainer</name>
    <description>Review Container is Blog App</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <start-class>com.reviewcontainer.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <!--Exclude the Tomcat dependency-->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-el</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>


        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!--tomcat embed jasper help REST to be converted to JSP-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.0.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/jquery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.sql/mysql-socket-factory -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring JDBC, Cloud GCP SQL Starter -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ReviewContainer</finalName>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <deploy.projectId>reviewcontainer</deploy.projectId>
                    <deploy.version>rc-003-snapshot</deploy.version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
"logMessage": "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter doStart: \norg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution\n\tat
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is located on properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/myBlog?cloudSqlInstance=reviewcontainerblog&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
```

If you check here on google's [community tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-spring-petclinic-on-app-engine-cloudsql#using_spring_datasource) and at Google Cloud Platform's Github [page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory) on "Creating the JDBC URL" :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/petclinic?cloudSqlInstance=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory

jdbc:mysql://google/<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false&user=<MYSQL_USER_NAME>&password=<MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD>
```

So, it is the **Instance Connection Name** and NOT the instance name. You can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-spring-petclinic-on-app-engine-cloudsql) from Google community tutorials which is quick helpful even if is for Flexible environment. Try it and let me know.

You can also check [this](https://medium.com/@DazWilkin/google-cloud-sql-4-ways-spring-a4f13ad32714) article which provides some other workaround on how to connect to CloudSQL from your Spring Application

Comment: thanks fro ur kind response, I tried all of the above you mentioned, nothing worked with me ! do u think I need to enable another google cloud api? connection work from my local machine, works from mysql workbench, but not working when I deploy my app. So annoying isn't it... still searching

Comment: On your pom.xml file you set on the <plugin> section the appengine-maven-plugin a wrong version. Follow this documentation [1] and you will see the available version.


[1]: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven#adding_the_app_engine_plugin_to_an_existing_project_optional

Comment: I tried everything still no luck, the plugin I added is cloud.tools instead of app engine as google recommended. But the problem is with the connection, I even tried to add my app engine ip in the DB public ips, still no luck. By the way I'm able to connect to DB from the MySQL workbench and also from my machine when I run the app. It's a bit confusion and annoying at the same time.. Let me know if you have different idea. Thanks

Comment: I was able to reproduce the [Pet Clinic project](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-spring-petclinic-on-app-engine-cloudsql) in GAE Flexible environment. Is there any specific reason you would like to use standard?

Comment: No not really, should I switch to Flexi?

Comment: If you don't mind, I advise you to use the Flexible environment since there is enough documentation and you can build your application following the Google's community tutorial. You can find more information about Google App Engine Flexible environment in [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/).

Comment: I was able to reproduce also a Spring Boot with Cloud SQL in standard environment and in the pom.xml I used dependency "org.springframework.cloud". I see that you did not use this anywhere in your code. Have you?

Comment: Did u try to connect to DB ? cause my problem with the connection to the DB !

Comment: I think i need to add my app-engine ip address to the sql, because app-engine doesn't have a static IP so i need to switch to google Compute engine to get static public ip

Comment: Both of my reproduction were with connection to Cloud SQL. Check your pom.xml because I think that you are using wrong dependencies.